# I can't run nginx on my ubunutu server how can i fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, tor

I am trying to setup ubuntu server, i checked nginx with 
"`sudo nginx -t`" command gives answer like that :

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid IPv6 address in "[192.168.0.28]:80" of the "listen" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion:23
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

and when i write "`service nginx start`" says
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

WHEN I WRITE systemctl status nginx.service

> nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy
>   server    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled;
>   vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since
>   Thu 2019-06-20 15:08:31 EEST; 1min 24s ago
>        Docs: man:nginx(8)   Process: 25213 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILU   Process:
>   27339 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
>   on; (code=exited, statu
>
> Jun 20 15:08:31 eysterty-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting A high
>   performance web server and a reverse pro Jun 20 15:08:31
>   eysterty-VirtualBox nginx[27339]: nginx: [emerg] invalid IPv6 address
>   in "[192.168.0.28] Jun 20 15:08:31 eysterty-VirtualBox nginx[27339]:
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test f Jun 20 15:08:31
>   eysterty-VirtualBox systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited,
>   code=exited statu Jun 20 15:08:31 eysterty-VirtualBox systemd[1]:
>   nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Jun 20 15:08:31
>   eysterty-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web
>   server and a reve

inside of /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/onionadress:

> # Default server configuration
>      #
>   server {
>     listen 192.168.0.28:80 default_server;
>     listen [192.168.0.28]:80 default_server;
>
> # SSL configuration
>     #
>     # listen 443 ssl default_server;
>     # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
>     #
>     # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
>     # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
>     #
>     # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
>     # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
>     #
>     # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
>     # Don't use them in a production server!
>     #
>     # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
>
> root /var/www/mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion/html;
>
> # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
>     index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
>
> server_name mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion;
>
> location / {
>         # First attempt to serve request as file, then
>         # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
>         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
>                 allow 192.168.0.28;
>
> }
>
> # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
>     #
>     #location ~ .php$ {
>     #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
>     #
>     #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
>     #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
>     #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
>     #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
>     #}
>
> # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
>     # concurs with nginx's one
>     #
>     #location ~ /.ht {
>     #   deny all;
>     #}
>    }
>
> # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
>    #
>    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and >symlink that
>    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
>    #
>    #server {
>    #    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
>    #    listen [::]:80;
>    #
>    #    server_name mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion;
>    #
>    #    root /var/www/onion;
>    #    index index.html;
>    #
>    #    location / {
>    #        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
>    #        allow 127.0.0.1;
>    #        deny all;
>    #    }
>    #}

Comment: Show your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.option files

Comment: default mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion mfekz7g3anx7pvmz.onion.save onion

Comment: [192.168.0.28] is not an IPv6 address